# Problem passing redux state to react-navigation prop using connect()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I've got a class component which needs to use a redux state, but I've noticed that using connect() does not work at all with @react-navigation. Here are my current files:

UserAuthenticationReducer

```
const initialState = null;

export let userAuthenticationReducer=(state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "LOGIN":
            return {
                ...state,
                    user:{
                        name:"Bobbington",
                        lastName: "TheThird"
                    }
                };
        case "LOGOUT":
            return {
                ...state,user:null
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default userAuthenticationReducer;
```

RootReducer

```
import userAuthenticationReducer from './Reducers';
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    userAuthenticationReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

LoginConnect

```
import {login,logout} from '../ReduxStates/LoginActions'
export const mapUserAuthenticationStateToProps = state => {
    return { 
        user: state?.userAuthenticationReducer?.user
    };
};
export const mapUserAuthenticationDispatchToProps ={
    login,
    logout
}
```

App

```
const rootStore = createStore(rootReducer)

const App =()=> {
    return (
        <Provider store={rootStore}>
            <MainRoutesContainer />
        </Provider>
    );
};
```

NavigationContainer

```
import { NavigationContainer} from "@react-navigation/native";
import {createStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/stack";
import {MainMenu} from "../Screens/MainMenu";
import React from 'react';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const StackRoute =()=>{
    return(
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="MainMenu">
            <Stack.Screen name="MainMenu" component={MainMenu} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}

export const MainRoutesContainer=()=>{
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <StackRoute />
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

Main Menu

```
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import {mapUserAuthenticationStateToProps,mapUserAuthenticationDispatchToProps} from '../ReduxStates/LoginConnect'

export class MainMenu extends Component{

    getUserState=()=>{
        console.log(this.props.user)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <Center flexDirection="column">
                <Text>
                    Main Menu
                </Text>
                <Button title="Log user" onPress={(event) => this.getUserState(event)}/>
            </Center>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapUserAuthenticationStateToProps,mapUserAuthenticationDispatchToProps)(MainMenu);
```

If i log the props.user of MainMenu, it'll come up as undefined. And after digging for a while i saw that if you did this:

```
const StackRoute =()=>{
    let mainComponent = connect(mapUserAuthenticationStateToProps,mapUserAuthenticationDispatchToProps)(MainMenu);
    return(
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="MainMenu">
            <Stack.Screen name="MainMenu" component={mainComponent} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

It would work, but only after I used a function from the reducer in the MainMenu component, otherwise it would still show up undefined on mount. Using a functional component with the useSelector hook works, but that is not an option I'm allowed to use. Am i doing something wrong with connect() or does React-Navigation v5 not work with redux's connect()?

Comment: Have you tried looking at [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/redux-integration/) and related pages?

Comment: Most of the documentation is using functional components. I tried some of the stuff they did on the documentation using class components, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You are importing the unconnected component. You `export default` your connected component, but are importing the named export "MainMenu", which is your unconnected component.

You have to

```
import MainMenu from "../Screens/MainMenu";
```

instead of

```
import {MainMenu} from "../Screens/MainMenu";
```

Comment: This did not fix it, the state still comes as undefined. [Pictured here](https://temp.sh/vAqQL/kkLi7hMQpZ.png)

Comment: Well, as long as `state?.userAuthenticationReducer` is `null`, that is the correct value from the store. Are you sure that's not the case?

(Also, more general: you are writing a very old style of Redux - and React - here. The general recommendation would be to use redux with function components and the react-redux hooks as well as the official redux toolkit. You are probably following very outdated resources. Please follow the officia tutorials: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index )

Comment: I've tried replacing initial state with other values but it comes undefined (also we both know that undefined!=null), but I guess I'll go towards the functional components route (even though that was really never an option in my use-case as this was just an example, though I'll try my best to implement it).

Comment: @ooatman your `initialState` sets the *entire object* as `null`.  Since you are using optional chaining, the initial value of `state?.userAuthenticationReducer?.user` is `undefined`.  You probably want `const initialState = {user: null};` instead of `const initialState = null;`